# Drawing subplots with multiple factors in Matlab

Tags: matlab, subplot, factors

I have been trying to find a way to draw the following plot (obtained in JMP) in Matlab. Could anyone please let me know whether there is a way to accomplish this in Matlab?

Here is my plot in JMP

[image]

P.S. The data is the average value for 2 variables, and the average is displayed across 3 factors (by fixing the 2 factor values and averaging over the other factor's levels of 0 and 1).

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you to use the subplot and bar functions in Matlab. I would do something like

```
subplot(2,2,1)
bar1
subplot(2,2,2)
bar2
subplot(2,2,3)
bar3
subplot(2,2,4)
bar4
```

If you want to have it all in a single image I don't think its possible

Comment: Thanks for suggestion but when I do subplot in the above manner, I get 4 different figures in quadrants. It does not generate the same figure as the one I create in JMP.

Comment: So you want a single figure subdivided in 4?

Comment: Short answer is yes. The issue is that if I have 4 separate figures at 4 quadrants, I would have to report the levels of three factors over (or under) each figure.  The above plot in JMP eliminates that by showing the three factor levels on a single figure.

Comment: I see what you mean, I've never seen anything like it in matlab. So my answer is you can't

Comment: Thanks for your interest.